# Is this method recommended when making a custom form element in vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, v-model

CInput.vue

```
<template>
  <input v-model="modelValueC">
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {computed} from "vue";

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    type: [String, Array, Date, Object, Number, null],
    default: null
  },
});
const modelValueC = computed({
  get() {
    return props.modelValue;
  },
  set(value) {
    emit('update:modelValue', value);
  }
});
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Or  need i  make this <input :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"> ?

Comment: They are the same, so it's up to you

Answer (score 0):

These approaches are outdated. Use it [defineModel()](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#definemodel):

```
/* App.vue */

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Input from './Input.vue';

const msg = ref('')
</script>

<template>
  <Input v-model="msg" />{{ msg }}
</template>
```

```
/* Input.vue */

<script setup>
const model = defineModel();
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="model">
</template>
```

[**Vue SFC Playground**](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UstOwzAQ/BXLl7RSSQ9wKm0lQD0UiYeAoy9Vugkujm35USpF+Xd2nTYUVOWU7M7seNbjht9Zm+8j8Bmf+8JJG5iHEO1SaFlb4wJrmIOStax0pmYZUrPbHltrG8MRyaepIjFiCF0Y7QOrfcUWJDHKsrHQ82l3CupjEaC2ahMAK8bmndr+qjZbUAvBcVRwNl02TVJpWxo/G+ETHjyeUsoq33mjcYeGhAQvTG2lAvdig0QXgs9YQgjbKGW+H1MvuAiTU7/4hOLrQn/nD9QT/NWBB7cHwXssbFwFoYNX789wwP8exDWiQvYA+AbeqEgeO9p91Fu0fcZLbtfptqWuPvzqEED701JklJht4guOd/8wsPqv3ev8Js0J3eIt9sFdeAXHFCkSzHELpdTwRNVojCkPxSn/x0lfwRH8m2L7A7KG2PE=)